# What comes first, the ruby chicken or the homebrew egg?

Tags: ruby

Whilst installing Ruby on OsX I noticed I could do so by using a package manager called Homebrew. This seemed like an easy option, so I took it. Everything worked smoothly. Life was good.

Being a curious fellow, I looked into what other benefits having homebrew installed would give me, and in my study found that Homebrew is written in ruby.

Woah, wait a minute! How is it then, that I can install Ruby using something that is written in Ruby, not already having Ruby on my system, and once installed said ruby based system I STILL have to install ruby separetely?

**Warning:** *Do not read this question aloud. You risk getting a Kaiser Chiefs single stuck in your head for the remainder of the day.*

Comment: How are you sure you don't have ruby on your system?

Comment: Clearly, I am not. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X comes pre bundled with system ruby. If you typed `which -a ruby` I'm pretty sure you'd get at least 3 results: system, homebrew and linked-to-homebrew.

It is also possible that homebrew installation is written in sh which in turn downloads and compiles ruby for itself.

**update**

Just do `ln -h /usr/bin/ruby`. It should tell you that it's symlink from system folder.

Comment: I get two, `/usr/bin/ruby` & `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

Comment: `/usr/bin/ruby` is the system one (which is linked from `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...`)